# Enable phoneNumbers of certain format using predicateForEnablingContact in CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, cncontactpicker

I'm looking to use [predicateForEnablingContact](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui/cncontactpickerviewcontroller/1619201-predicateforenablingcontact) inside a [CNContactPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui/cncontactpickerviewcontroller) to only enable contacts that have phoneNumbers that match the following regular expression `^\\+1[2-9]\\d{9}$`.

This will mean looking at a contacts phoneNumbers and checking to see if at least one or more matches the following expression.

I started small by using the following trying to following the NSPredicate docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795):

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY self.phoneNumbers.'value'.'stringValue' BEGINSWITH %@", "1111")
contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = predicate
```

However, I'm unable to get past this part. I always seem to get the following error in my logs when running:

```
2023-06-11 21:31:15.703957+0100 Test2[9610:702640] [CNUI ERROR] Error when showing picker: Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=300 "(null)" UserInfo={CNValidationErrors=(
"Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=400 \"Invalid Predicate\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Predicate, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed because its predicate is invalid.}"
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I'd write a `NSPredicate` that matches the ruleset above please?

Edit:

I have also tried using

```
NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count > 0 AND SUBQUERY(phoneNumbers, $phoneNumber, $phoneNumber.value.stringValue != nil).@count > 0"`
```

But get the following...

```
predicate is invalid., CNKeyPaths=(\n \"value.stringValue\"\n)}"
```

Comment: This is odd. If you have an `NSArray` of `CNContact`, then using `array.filtered(using: predicate)` where `predicate` is `NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(phoneNumbers, $phoneNumber, $phoneNumber.value.stringValue CONTAINS %@).@count > 0", "555")` then you get the correct results. But the same predicate for `predicateForEnablingContact` yields the frustrating "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed because its predicate is invalid." message you are seeing.

Comment: @HangarRash Nice idea to try using array.filtered - although the fact the same predicate works there but not on the contact picker makes me even more confused now…

Comment: What's really strange is that you can't use, for example, `CNContact.predicateForContacts(matching:)` with `predicateForEnablingContact`. The contact picker won't even appear. So it seems that the contact picker is doing some really strange non-standard stuff with the predicate you give it.

Comment: Try this - 
let phoneNumberRegex = "^\\+1[2-9]\\d{9}$"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(phoneNumbers, $phoneNumber, $phoneNumber.value.stringValue MATCHES %@).@count > 0", phoneNumberRegex)
contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = predicate

Comment: Thanks @teja_D, unfortunately with that example I still get the predicate as invalid:

`Code=400 \"Invalid Predicate\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Predicate, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed because its predicate is invalid., CNKeyPaths=(\n    \"value.stringValue\"\n)}`

The documentation simply references NSPredicate (and there's no indication that this is a special case) so why would it be seen as invalid when passed to the picker ...really confusing.